# Xamarin C# data between server and client

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httprequest, apprequests

I recently started making a android app with c#(xamarin) and my goal was to send data to a database, I always got an error when connecting to the mysql server (server does not exist or connection refused).

Then I searched for a fix and realised that it was a bad idea to connect directly to the sql server.

My question is how do such simple "requests and responses" work?

And what is the best way to get data from a client to a database or server?

Sry if the question is makes no sense, until now I just worked with simple sql connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do it, would be to create an API layer that will talk to the database and your app would talk to the API 
I recently did an app on Xamarin and used the following to build the API:

1. ASP.NET WEBAPI2 (for sending and accepting JSON data)
2. Entity Framework 6.0 (for db modelling, reading writing)

to secure the API's I'm using basic http authentication over SSL (although it's not preferebly but secures it in a simple way)

for the xmarain app, you can potentially use something like restsharp portable to talk the REST based API

Comment: Ok thank you how do I set up a API server and what is the best way to host it?

Comment: you can follow the tutorial here: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

in the next steps section, you will also see the link to using it with entity framework 6

for hosting - you might consider microsoft azure - although I haven't personally used it, we have our own servers - but i can be good if you have no infrastructure of your own and don't wish to manage the server yourself

Comment: But I have to run this model on a microsoft .net server right?

Comment: yep, if you use the technologies I mentioned to build the API - then it would have to be hosted on microsoft IIS server - (azure if I understand correctly, also has a service model, which deploys it on the cloud and you manage your app through a dashboard - so you won't actually be managing the server on azure)

Comment: yes, server side API can be any technology you choose